# Divergence of subsequence of sequence which diverges

Tags: limsup-and-liminf, divergence-operator

I have to prove that given a sequence {a<sub>n</sub>}<sub>n</sub>, with lim sup a<sub>n</sub> = infinity, prove that there is a sub-sequence a<sub>n</sub><sub><sub>k</sub></sub> of a<sub>n</sub> that diverges to infinity.

I used the Theorem which states that for any sequence which has a limit (possibly infinite), all of it's sub-sequences have the same limit. As a<sub>n</sub> clearly diverges to infinity, the limit of all sub-sequences is infinity, and thus all sub-sequences diverge to infinity.

Does this work, or is there something I am shortcutting passed something important?

Comment: Nothing implies that $(a_{n})$ diverges to infinity...

Comment: If an diverges to infinity, then the sequence has no limit, so you can't use your theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work; mainly because the problem statement does not require the sequence to have a limit $+\infty$.

The symbol $\limsup$ doesn't mean a limit, but rather an 'asymptotic upper bound'.
See Wikipedia [Limit superior and limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) for definitions.

In your case the sequence is said to be unbound from above (it reaches larger and larger values), but not necessarily to converge to $+\infty$. As an example sequences
$$a_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{if }\ 2\vert n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
or
$$a_n = n\cdot(-1)^n$$
both satisfy $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = +\infty$$ although none of them has $\lim a_n = \infty$.
Instead, the former one has $\liminf = 0$ whilst the latter has $\liminf = -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that theorem, since $\lim_n a_n = +\infty$ isn't necessarily true as CiaPan has pointed out. You can however construct a subsequence as follows: because 
$\limsup_n a_n = \lim_n \sup \{ a_k \mid k \geq n\} = +\infty$, for every $C > 0$ there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_m : = \sup \{a_k \mid k \geq m\} \geq C$ for all $m \geq N$.

So there is some $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_{n_1} \geq 2$, then there must be some $m_1 \geq n_1$ such that $a_{m_1} \geq 1$ by definition of the supremum. Now take $n_2 > n_1$ such that $s_{n_2} \geq 3$, again there must be some $m_2 \geq n_2$ such that $a_{m_2} \geq 2$. Continuing this process results in a subsequence $(a_{m_k})_k$ such that $a_{m_k} \geq k$ and so we must have $\lim_k a_{m_k} = +\infty$.